# How do I simplify(expand) this Boolean expression?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

Expression - `(A OR B OR C OR D) AND (!B AND !D)`

I know that with distributive property, it holds that `(a OR b) AND (c OR d) = (a AND c) OR (a AND d) OR (b AND c) or (b AND d)` but I'm not sure how it will work if the second group has an `AND`

Steps in the answer would help.

Comment: Yes by `!B`, I mean `NOT B`. I just went through De morgan's law. So 
`(A OR B OR C OR D) AND (NOT B AND NOT D) = (A OR B OR C OR D) AND NOT (B OR D)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so you have:

$(A \lor B \lor C \lor D) \land (\neg B \land \neg D)$

Now, notice that this is a conjunction (an 'AND' statement) whose right conjunct is a conjunction itself. In a case like that, you can actually drop the parentheses, and thus get:

$(A \lor B \lor C \lor D) \land \neg B \land \neg D$

This is what is called a *generalized* conjunction; a conjunction that can conjunct together any number of terms. In this case, you have $3$ terms

And by the way, note that the left conjunct is already a *generalized* disjunction (of $4$ terms), so this is really nothing unusual.

Now, any logical equivalence principle you would normally apply to a 'normal' conjunction with $2$ conjuncts, you can still apply to any $2$ conjuncts of a generalized conjunction.

For example, one very useful simplification principle is:

**Reduction**

$\neg P \land (P \lor Q) \Leftrightarrow \neg P \land Q$

To understand this: note that $\neg P$ is definitely true ... so how can $P \lor Q$ be true as well? Clearly it must be that $Q$ is true. So, the left side implies the right side, and going from right to left is trivial, since $Q$ implies $P \lor Q$.  But, going from left to right, which is how we typically use Reduction, because is simplifies things, we say that in the presence of $\neg P$, the term $P \lor Q$ 'reduces' to just $Q$

OK, so we can apply Reduction to your statement twice:  The $\neg B$ will reduce the $A \lor B \lor C \lor D$ term to $A \lor C \lor D$, and the $\neg D$ term will further reduce that to $A \lor C$. Hence, we end up with:

$(A\lor C) \land \neg B \land \neg D$

If you want this more formally, you can state the Association principle, which states that $P \land (Q \land R) \Leftrightarrow (P \land Q) \land R$, and thus makes clear that you could write $P \land Q \land R$ without any ambiguity, as a justification for dropping the parentheses at the start. As such, it formally looks like:

$$(A \lor B \lor C \lor D) \land (\neg B \land \neg D)$$

$$\overset{\text{Association}}{\Leftrightarrow}$$

$$(A \lor B \lor C \lor D) \land \neg B \land \neg D$$

$$\overset{\text{Reduction x 2}}{\Leftrightarrow}$$

$$(A\lor C) \land \neg B \land \neg D$$